# What is wrong with my "hello world" in the lines of code?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, bios

I was trying to load a "Hello World" string in the Qemu, but it only shows a letter "H". I am very new to this, thanks in advance for trying to help me out :D
I am doing this on a Windows Operating System.

---

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0X7C00]

MOV SI, BOOTLOADSTR
CALL Printstring
JMP $

Printcharacter:
MOV AH, 0x0E
MOV BH, 0x00
MOV BL, 0x07

INT 0x10
RET

Printstring
next_character:
MOV AL, [SI]
INC SI
OR AL, AL
JZ exit_function
CALL Printcharacter
exit_function
RET

;DATA
BOOTLOADSTR db 'Hello World', 0

TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) DB 0
DW 0XAA55
```

[The image of the qemu should be here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NrSe.png)

Comment: After `CALL Printcharacter` I don't see you going back and processing the next character. Seems like you are missing a `jmp next_character` soit only does the first letter in the string and exits.

Comment: To make your bootloader code more robust you should be setting DS to 0 (at the start) since you use an `org 07c00`  You can do that with `xor ax, ax` `mov ds, ax`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: tag usage question: is `[bootloader]` appropriate for a stand-alone thing that *doesn't* actually load any more code from disk?  When I retagged this yesterday, I left it out because I wasn't sure it applied to code like this that's loaded as an MBR boot sector.  But probably that's a more useful meaning for the tag, because that describes the environment the code runs in rather than its purpose.  Maybe the tag-usage popup could use an edit to clarify.

Comment: @PeterCordes: It is technically still a bootloader, and keeping these questions under the one tag makes sense given that these questions are often related to specific issues that code that loads/doesn't load more than one sector will encounter. It is also possible that this kind of code will evolve into something that load sectors later on.

Comment: @PeterCordes : To be pedantic: An interesting thing is that MBR may not even be what this is if it is on non partitioned media (The VBR is the MBR in that case and has a BIOS Parameter Block). An MBR generally applies to partitioned media here the MBR is the first sector of the media (and doesn't have a BPB but does have a partition table) and the VBRs are the first sectors of the partitions. VBRs and MBRs get loaded at 0x7c00 in memory at some point.

Comment: @PeterCordes : If someone was asking about how partition tables in the first sector work I'd consider tagging it as MBR, as it would be something very specific to that class of boot sector.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I could compromise and say calling it "bootsector" instead of "bootloader". Then it wouldn't matter anymore. But the tag has been around forever.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry if i caused any problem or confusion, it is only because i started learning this myself so i am a monkey on a keyboard basically.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code seems to incorrectly referencing [DS:SI]... it seems that you're only grabbing a single byte from [DS:SI] try using `lodsb` to collect bytes continuously till `NULL` Terminated **[CHAR_STREAM]** `[0x00]`

Might I suggest trying this bit of code; I've included comments and the `lodsb` instruction with simple details to explain the process:

```
[bits   16]                             ; Declare CPU Instructions as [REAL_MODE]
[org    0x0000]                         ; Organize Memory to Start @ [0x0000]
                                        ; We'll Manually setup Memory Organization Later...

jmp _glEntry                            ; Relocate to Function:

output16_char_array:                    ; Legacy BIOS Output ChAR_STREAM Function
    xor ax, ax                          ; Zero [AX] Register
    mov ah, 0x0E                        ; Assign [0x0E] to [AX] : (Legacy BIOS Function Code for BIOS Display)
                                        ; Continue Code Execution:
    .output16_char_array_loop:
        lodsb                           ; Collect Single Byte from [DS:SI] and increment SI by 1 : ([AL] = [DS:SI]; inc [SI])
        or  al, al                      ; Check Whether [AL] is [0x00]
        jz  .output16_char_array_done   ; [AL] == [0x00] Proceed to Function:
        int 0x10                        ; [AL] != [0x00] Continue to Display Hex->ASCII [CHAR]
        jmp .output16_char_array_loop   ; Relocate [CS] to create an Infinite Loop...

    .output16_char_array_done:
        ret                             ; Return to Calling [CS] Memory Position...



WELCOME_MSG db  "Hello, World!",    0x0D,   0x0A,   0x00



_glEntry:
    cli                                 ; Disable CPU Interrupts
    xor ax, ax                          ; Zero [AX] Register
    mov ax, 0x07E0                      ; Assign [0x07E0] to [AX] : (0x07E0)
    mov ss, ax                          ; Assign [AX] to [SS] : ([AX]*[0x0010]) : (0x7E00)
    mov sp, 0x1000                      ; Assign [0x1000] to [SP] : (0x1000) ([0x07E0]:[0x1000])
    sti                                 ; Enable CPU Interrupts
                                        ; Continue Code Execution:
    xor ax, ax                          ; Zero [AX] Register
    mov ax, 0x07C0                      ; Assign [0x07C0] to [AX] : (0x07C0)
    mov ds, ax                          ; Assign [AX] to [DS] : ([AX]*[0x0010]) : (0x7C00)
                                        ; Continue Code Execution:
    mov si, WELCOME_MSG                 ; Assign [WELCOME_MSG] to [SI] : (0x[....])
    call    output16_char_array         ; Call our Output [CHAR_STREAM] Function
                                        ; Continue Code Execution on Return:
    xor ax, ax                          ; Zero [AX] Register
    int 0x16                            ; Call BIOS Await Keystroke Interrupt
    xor ax, ax                          ; Zero [AX] Register
    int 0x19                            ; Call BIOS Reboot Interrupt
                                        ; Continue Code Execution if interrupts fail...
    cli                                 ; Disable CPU Interrupts
    hlt                                 ; Halt CPU Execution:



times   510 - ( $ - $$ )    db  0x00        ; Pad [BOOTSECTOR] with [0x00] up to 510 Bytes...
dw  0xAA55                      ; Assign [MAGIC_MBR] Value...
```

Here's the Respected Outcome:

[image: Output of 'Hello, World!']